# debugging custom binary tree specific the total(maximum) depth method

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-tree

As for my question: I have a Node class:

```
public class Node<E> {

  private E value;
  private Node<E> left;
  private Node<E> right;

  public Node(E value) {
    this.value = value;
    this.left = null;
    this.right = null;
  }
```

and this class has two methods which calculate the depth of the node (binary tree). The method `totaldepth()` I wrote myself and it gives an incorrect answer, for which I need your help debugging. The method `maxDepth(Node node)` gives the correct answer and was used as reference material by me. Could you help me debug `totalDepth` method as to me it looks the same as `maxDepth`by the result.

incorrect code:

```
public int totalDepth() {
    // initialize variabele depth
    int depth = 0;
    // reached leaf return 0
    if (right == null && left == null) {
      return 0;
    }

    // not yet reached leaf, continue deeper
    else {
      int leftdepth = 0;
      int rightdepth = 0;
      // left node is not null continue going left
      if (left != null) {
        leftdepth = left.totalDepth();
      }
      // right node is not null continue going right
      if (right != null) {
        rightdepth = right.totalDepth();
      }

      if (leftdepth > rightdepth) {
        // 1 is needed because each call to totalDepth raises depth by 1
        depth = leftdepth + 1;
      }
      else {
        depth = rightdepth + 1;
      }
    }
    return depth;
  }
```

correct code:

```
public int maxDepth(Node node) {
    if (node == null) {
      return (0);
    }
    else {
      // compute the depth of each subtree
      int leftDepth = maxDepth(node.left);
      int rightDepth = maxDepth(node.right);
      // use the larger one
      if (leftDepth > rightDepth)
        return (leftDepth + 1);
      else
        return (rightDepth + 1);
    }
  }
```

Also I'm just starting to learn how to code so forgive me for all the inefficient things I'm doing. Thanks in advance for helping me!

Comment: I assume the totalDepth method is included in a Node class in this case?

Comment: sorry, if that was unclear, but yes!

Answer (score 0):

Your `totalDepth` method will not work, because you have a tree, and you don't actually know, how many elements you have from the left and the right. Balanced this tree or not. So, only way to walk throw the tree, is to use `Breadth-first search` or `Depth-first search` algorithm, and they are based of recursion function like `maxDepth(Node node)` method.